# How to check a bulk of ip for reverse dns?

Tags: command-line, scripts, dns, ip

Is there a way to check to reverse DNS check for loads of IPs, I have a list of IP I want to check?

I know you're are able to do these individually:

```
host <ip-address>
```

and

```
dig -x <ip-address>
```

Also, is there a way to export them?

Comment: Yes, very much possible. I'll write a small script in a minute. Please wait

Comment: You can use Nirsoft FastResolver on Windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xargs` provides an optin `--arg-file`. With `-L1` option  to treat each line as argument, the simplest command we can make is as follows

```
$ xargs -L1 --arg-file=ip-addr.txt dig +short -x
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
resolver2.opendns.com.
```

If it's necessary to display the IP address next to the resolved domain, we can also do:

```
$ xargs -L1 --arg-file=ip-addr.txt sh -c 'printf "%s: " "$1"; dig +short -x "$1"' sh
8.8.8.8: google-public-dns-a.google.com.
208.67.220.220: resolver2.opendns.com.
```

Of course, `xargs` is an extra process. What if we wanted to only use shell and `dig` ? With bash version 4 and over, we can use `mapfile` or `readarray` to get lines of the text file into array, and then process items in a loop:

```
$ mapfile -t -d $'\n' < ip-addr.txt
$ for i in "${MAPFILE[@]}" ; do printf "%s:" "$i"; dig +short -x "$i"; done
8.8.8.8:google-public-dns-a.google.com.
208.67.220.220:resolver2.opendns.com.
```

If the IP addresses are few and don't require a long text file, POSIXly, we could use `set` to define values as positional parameters:

```
$ set -- 8.8.8.8 208.67.220.220
$ for i ; do printf "%s:" "$i"; dig +short -x "$i"; done
8.8.8.8:google-public-dns-a.google.com.
208.67.220.220:resolver2.opendns.com.
```

---

We can also use `dig -x $IP_ADDRESS +short` in a script like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C
# without specifying 'in' part, bourne-like shells default
# to iterating over positional parameters
for item
do
     domain=$(dig -x "$item"  +short)
     # this logic can also be reversed with
     # [ "x$domain" = "x" ] && echo "empty" || echo "$domain"
     if [ -n "$domain"  ] ;
     then
         echo "$domain"
     else
         echo "$item" result is NULL
     fi
done
```

Demo of sample usage(all ip addresses given as space separeted):

```
$ ./reverse_dns_lookup.sh 8.8.8.8 74.125.193.94 151.101.193.69                 
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
ig-in-f94.1e100.net.
151.101.193.69 result is NULL
```

As you can see , in the last example our DNS server didn't find domain for the ip address we gave it. In such case we can use a different DNS server, for instance open_dns with `dig @208.67.220.220 $IP_ADDRESS +short`

In the demo above, the ip addresses are provided on command line, like `./reverse_dns_lookup.sh ADDRESS1 ADDRESS2 ADDRESS2` but you also can use a file for that, like so:

```
$ cat ip_addresses.txt |  xargs ./reverse_dns_lookup.sh                          <
google-public-dns-a.google.com.
resolver2.opendns.com.
192.30.253.112 result is NULL
```

**Alternative script version**:

Here's alternative version of the script that prints the AUTHORITY section from `dig's` output. This may be much better and more reliable than just `+short` version. NOTE: this uses `8.8.8.8` , which is Google's public DNS. Use a different server if you feel necessary.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C
for item
do
 domain=$(dig @8.8.8.8  -x "$item" +noall +authority +answer)
 if [ -n "$domain"  ] ;
 then
     echo "$domain"
 else
     echo "$item" result is NULL
 fi
done
```

Demo:

```
$ cat ip_addresses.txt |  xargs ./reverse_dns_lookup.sh 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 -x 8.8.8.8 +noall +authority +answer
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa.   21390   IN  PTR google-public-dns-a.google.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 -x 208.67.220.220 +noall +authority +answer
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
220.220.67.208.in-addr.arpa. 6674 IN    PTR resolver2.opendns.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 -x 192.30.253.112 +noall +authority +answer
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
253.30.192.in-addr.arpa. 10 IN  SOA ns1.p16.dynect.net. ops.github.com. 6 3600 600 604800 60
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but where in the script do I define the list of the IPs?

Comment: @YenDeng the IP addresses are given on command line. I'll add a little more info about that in a second.

Comment: @YenDeng I added more info to the answer. Also added alternative script version. That should be more reliable

Comment: Hi Serg, sorry for being annoying. It says that ./reverse_dns_look.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Unsure what is wrong with this

Comment: Try deleting that line, and write that line again. Somehow you got a control character added there. Just retype it, `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: Some reason, it's not getting recognised. It says "No such file or directory"

Comment: @YenDeng did you make the script executable ? `chmod +x ./reverse_dns_lookup.sh`

Comment: Yen, i have to leave. Please leave me comment here if you have other questions. I will check back as soon as I return to the site. Thanks

Comment: Yes I have made the file executable but somewhat it's not being nice to me :(

Thank you for your time and let me know when you're back!

Comment: @YenDeng You need to be in the folder where both `ip_addresses.txt` and `./reverse_dns_lookup‌​.sh` resides. If you omit `./` before script name, it won't run, even if it is executable. Because it is not in your environment variable ([PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html)).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick and dirty one liner:
Contents of ip-addresses.txt:

```
$ cat ip-addresses.txt
    1.2.3.4
    1.1.1.1
    222.222.222.222
    23.12.34.56
    8.8.8.8
    208.67.222.220
```

Replace txt with your file that contains addresses, separated by newlines:

```
$ cat ip-addresses.txt | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo "%:$(dig -x % +short)"' >> dig-output.txt
```

If you append to dig-output.txt like above, contents of that file will be like below, if reverse DNS lookup is successfull, `IP:NAME`, if not, `IP:(NULL)`

```
$ cat dig-output.txt
1.2.3.4:
1.1.1.1:
222.222.222.222:
23.12.34.56:a23-12-34-56.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.
8.8.8.8:google-public-dns-a.google.com.
208.67.222.220:resolver3.opendns.com.
```

If IP addresses are coming from another process, you can directly pipe to xargs.

Edit: If you must have a word such as null (inspired by @Serg) in case of a lookup failure, you can use the command below:

```
$ cat ip-addresses.txt | xargs -I % bash -c '{ query=$(dig -x % +short); if [ -z $query ]; then query=null;fi; echo %:$query; }'
```

- `cat ip-addresses.txt` # Print IP addresses to `STDOUT`. If you don't want to `cat` from file, you can directly pipe from another process like `command | xargs ...`
- `xargs -I % bash -c` # Take each line from left of pipe, use `%` as placeholder, run `bash` command that follows within single quotes
- `dig` IP address that comes from placeholder `%` by `xargs`, assign to variable `query`. If result happens to be `null` (zero length), assign string 'null' word to `query` variable, then print as `IP:result`

Demo:

```
$ cat ip-addresses.txt | xargs -I % bash -c '{ query=$(dig -x % +short); if [ -z $query ]; then query=null;fi; echo %:$query; }'
1.2.3.4:null
1.1.1.1:null
222.222.222.222:null
23.12.34.56:a23-12-34-56.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.
8.8.8.8:google-public-dns-a.google.com.
208.67.222.220:resolver3.opendns.com.
```

Comment: How would I export the results?

Comment: Do you intend to save to a file?

Comment: Yes, if that's possible

Comment: Simply append  `>> my-log-filename.txt` to the end of the command.

Comment: @YenDeng I edited my answer and fixed some stuff. Might be more useful now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man.html)

You can just

```
nmap -R -sL -Pn 1.2.3.0/24 | grep '('
```

- `-n/-R` Never do DNS resolution/Always resolve [default: sometimes]
- `-sL` List Scan - simply list targets to scan
- `-Pn` Treat all hosts as online -- skip host discovery. Remove this to get just what respond to ping.

The `grep` leave just resolved reverse DNS and some useful lines.

Add `--dns-servers x.x.x.x` to use a specific DNS server [like 1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1/).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the shell example shown in another answer I decided a Perl version suited me better so I created this file "batch_dns_by_ip.pl".  You put a list of IP address in a text file that you will pipe into the program.

The code should look like this and you will want to make the file executable:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my @domains;
my $address;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  $address = $_;
  $address =~ s/ *//g;
  @domains = ();
  @domains = `dig -x "$address" +short`;
  chomp(@domains);
  if ( "$domains[0]" eq "" ) {
    $domains[0] = "NULL";
  }
  printf( "addr: %15s names: %s", $address, $domains[0] );
  if ( "$domains[1]" eq "" ) {
    print "\n";
  }
  else {
    printf( ", %s\n", $domains[1] );
  }
}
```

A run might look like this:

```
$ cat myips | ./batch_dns_by_ip.pl
addr:  216.58.219.238 names: lga25s41-in-f14.1e100.net., lga25s41-in-f238.1e100.net.
addr:  151.101.129.69 names: NULL
addr:         8.8.8.8 names: google-public-dns-a.google.com.
addr:     10.49.11.62 names: nyalbdnsvip01.miscny.nyenet., nyalbcwgbvip01-vlan401.miscny.nyenet.
addr:  69.172.201.153 names: NULL
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This works, but note that the input file must have have each IP on its own separate line.